# How to avoid StreamBuilder refreshing when using setState

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I’m using a StreamBilder that’s a restaurant menu, and I put a button “Buy” which has a setState. And every time I push this button, the page refreshes and scrolls up to the top, and I don’t want it. Is there anyway to do that without refreshing?